# Creating a PDF using Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, pdf, xamarin

I am trying to create a PDF document that can then be open via an external application. The user is selecting an arbitrary number of images which are stored in a `List<byte[]>`. Disregarding this, I cannot get the following to even create a blank PDF that can be opened. If I try opening the generated PDF, Adobe Reader says that the file has is not supported or has been damaged. I am not sure where the error is occurring since the PDF seems to be generated. I would imagine the problem occurs when trying to write the PDF to the FileStream. What is the issue with the following code?

```
private void CreatePDFWithImages(List<byte[]> images)
    {
        // create PDF
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

        // create a page description
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(612, 792, 0).Create();

        // draw image to pag
        for (int i = 0; i < images.Count; i++)
        {
            // start page
            PdfDocument.Page page = pdf.StartPage(pageInfo);

            // create bitmap from each byte[]
            byte[] currentByteArray = images[i];
            Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options options = new Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.InMutable = true;
            Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(currentByteArray, 0, currentByteArray.Length, options);

            // matrix
            Android.Graphics.Matrix matrix = new Android.Graphics.Matrix();
            matrix.PreTranslate(300, 300);
            matrix.PreScale(2, 2);

            // add image to the page
            page.Canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);

            // finish the page
            pdf.FinishPage(page);
        }

        // save PDF
        string path = "/mnt/shared/POC_Documents/temp.pdf";
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        pdf.WriteTo(fileStream);

        // close PDF
        pdf.Close();

        // try to open...
        this.OpenPDF(path);
    }
```

Comment: Having the same problem here, Got any Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In the pageInfo you have to pass page number as 1 instead of 0
and

If you add

```
fileStream.flush();
```

after this line

```
pdf.WriteTo(fileStream);
```

It will create the pdf